# Boost::threads work in debug, don't in release

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, gcc, boost-thread

I started doing threads about an hour ago and am having some trouble where the debug mode does what I expect and the release mode cashes.

**Debug**

> g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/foo.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/foo.o foo.cpp
>
> Whatever 2222222222

**Release**

> g++    -c -O2 -MMD -MP -MF build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/foo.o.d -o build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/foo.o foo.cpp
>
> Whatever
>
> RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 49ms)

**Class**

```
#include "foo.h"
#define NUMINSIDE 10

foo::foo()
{
    inside = new int[NUMINSIDE];
}

void foo::workerFunc(int input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMINSIDE; i++)
    {
        inside[i] += input;
    }
}

void foo::operate()
{
    std::cout << "Whatever" << std::endl;
    boost::thread thA(boost::bind(&foo::workerFunc, this, 1));
    boost::thread thB(boost::bind(&foo::workerFunc, this, 1));
    thA.join();
    thB.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMINSIDE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << this->inside[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**main**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo* myFoo = new foo();
    myFoo->operate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks ok, what's the contents of foo.h ?

Comment: I can't see any code that could be responsible for the "RUN FAILED" output, so maybe the problem is in some code that you did not show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized `inside` array. Add initialization code to `foo::foo()`

```
foo::foo()
{
    inside = new int[NUMINSIDE];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMINSIDE; i++)
    {
        inside[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

It works only in debug because it is undefined behavior.

Comment: While this true, I doubt it's responsible for the crash.

Comment: I don't see any other problems besides memory leaks

Comment: Crazy, but that seemed to fix it. Whats strange is that I had no problems building similar code. It would just operate on some junk memory.

Comment: "Whats strange is that I had no problems building similar code." It does not matter. If you are invoking UB than anything can happen - crash, operation on junk values.